# Protecting samba shares with ubuntu 10.04

Tags: security, samba, password, share

I'm using a linux distribution based on Ubuntu 10.04 (Backtrack 5 R1).
I successfully managed to create a samba share that is read/write accessible to everyone in my network.
I want to protect this share with a username / password combo. Any host in my network that can provide this combo can access the share and edit its contents.

Is this technically feasible? If yes, how can I do so?

Comment: I googled and tried to edit authentication mode, add smb passwords with "smbpasswd" , etc.. But with no results.

Comment: Very feasible. I think we need more information on what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things you can do to secure samba from passwords to kerberos.

First, to access the share, you will be using a user name and password configured on the samba server.

I assume you already have a (login) user.

You then assign a samba password to the user

```
sudo smbpasswd -a username
sudo smbpasswd -e username
```

You then define your shares in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

```
sudo -e /etc/samba/smb.conf

gksu gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

In the section where you define your shared directory

```
[private]
comment = private share
path = /path/to/share/point
browseable = no
read only = no
guest ok = no
```

After making those edits, restart the samba server.

```
sudo service samba restart
```

There are a number of security features for samba, see also

[Ubuntu Server Guide Securing Samba](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/samba-fileprint-security.html)

[Ubuntu Community Wiki Samba Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide)

Comment: I only have "root" user. Do I need to create a new user?

Comment: personally, I would create a non-root user, but you do not need to.